# How to install archived R packages on windows machine?

Tags: r, package, installation

I am trying to install the archived R packages from these websites:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sentiment/
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/

However, I cannot get it to work for around 2 hours now! I have been using a variety of different approaches including installing them manually, nothing worked :(

Do you know a trick for that?

Comment: please guys i am dying to receive an answer it is of incredible importance for me please help me :( :D

Comment: please post the code you are using to install the packages.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What's R version you're using? What errors did you get?

Comment: Check out the MRAN Time Machine snapshots to lead you in the right direction.  Unfortunately they do not store snapshots earlier than 2014.

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please consider clicking the tick next to the post. This let's the community know your question has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can try to install archived packages.

1. Using the `devtools` package.

   ```
   require(devtools)
   install_version("sentiment", version = "0.2", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
   install_version("Rstem", version = "0.4.1", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
   ```
2. Installing from source in R

   ```
   sentimenturl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sentiment/sentiment_0.2.tar.gz"
   rstemurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz"
   install.packages(sentimenturl, repos=NULL, type="source")
   install.packages(rstemurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
   ```
3. Installing from source from the command line

   ```
   wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sentiment/sentiment_0.2.tar.gz
   R CMD INSTALL sentiment_0.2.tar.gz
   wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz
   R CMD INSTALL Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz
   ```

For a Windows machine you will most likely need to have `Rtools` installed. You can follow the installation steps here:
https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows

Credit:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Hope that helps!

Comment: And note that in Windows, you'll probably need [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed.