# Problems downloading edgeR - R version 4.0.2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I have an error in I presume downloading the package edgeR. I am using R version 4.0.2. The error was:

```
Error in DGEList(counts = feature_count, samples = sample_info,  : 
  could not find function "DGEList"
```

I had downloaded edgeR above using the following code and activated the library:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("edgeR")
library("edgeR")
```

When I installed edgeR with BiocManager::install("edgeR"), I got this error message and so I thought I was missing a package:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘edgeR’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘locfit’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘edgeR’ was built under R version 4.0.3
```

I tried to download the library locfit separately using `BiocManager::install("locfit")` and then `library("locfit")` however it says that the library could not be found `library("locfit") Error in library("locfit") : there is no package called ‘locfit’`

Thank you in advance for any help on how to download edgeR correctly. I am a bit stumped!

Comment: What was the output of `BiocManager::install("locfit")`? Where there any errors listed?

Comment: I had a long message (too long to post here as over the character limit!), with some errors including this one when I typed in ```warnings()```:
```1: package ‘locfit’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)```
I have had many of the bioinformatics packages say that they are not available for R version 4.0.2 and wondered if I was doing something wrong?

Comment: According to CRAN, the latest [locfit version requires at least R 4.1](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=locfit). You seem to be using an older version of R. You can either update your R version or [install an archived version of the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533331/how-to-install-archived-r-packages-on-windows-machine)